# Why is my simple for loop not working?

Tags: android, for-loop, arraylist, android-tablelayout

I have this for loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<playerList.size();i++){
            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            String sPlayerName = playerList.get(i);
            TextView playerName = new TextView(this);
            playerName.setText(sPlayerName);
            row.addView(playerName);
            table.addView(row);
        }
```

where playerList is an ArrayList of strings and table is a TableLayout.
What I want this line of code to do is take the information from the ArrayList playerlist and put in into the TableLayout table.
The problem is when I add strings to playerList, for example say I add "Bob", "James", and "Dylan", the table I want to output is:

```
Bob
James
Dylan
```

But the table that gets output is:

```
Bob
Bob
James
Bob
James
Dylan
```

The table seems to start again from the first name instead of going straight to the next one and I don't understand why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: I found the solution to my problem, and it had nothing to do with the code above. The problem was with other code in my program.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a `TableLayout` instead of a `ListView`? If you used `ListView` you could simply use an `ArrayAdapter` and everything would be handled for you.

Comment: @Squonk Yah, I want to create another column to the table as well, and I thought it would be easier to use a TableLayout rather than a ListView to do so.

Comment: If it's only 2 columns I'd still prefer to use `ListView` as all the binding of data to data views is handled for you.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding duplicate players.  So you need to create a find function to check that the player you are about to add is not already in the table.  If the player is then you could then update the view of the player - for that you would have to delete the existing player row and insert in this row the updated player details.

You could do something like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<playerList.size();i++){
    String sPlayerName = playerList.get(i);
    if(!find_player(sPlayerName)) {
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        TextView playerName = new TextView(this);
        playerName.setText(sPlayerName);
        row.addView(playerName);
        table.addView(row);
    }       
}
```

Comment: How would I create the find function so that !find_player does that?

Comment: You would search for the player in the table.  If found you could return the row number found, then -1 could be not found.  But that's a detail.  You just need to check that the player is not already in the list before adding.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like whenever you're appending to the list and invoking the for loop, you're also adding views after those already existing in `table`.

Call `table.removeAllViews()` before the loop to clear the table first.

Comment: That doesn't seem to solve the problem, I appreciate it though.

Comment: Consider adding some additional problem details to the question then.